# Postfix error in regexp in body checks expression

Tags: postfix, regex

Emails containing: blablabla.icu/blabla should be blocked. I get confused with this rule to block and emails that contain a link which address finish with .icu/:

```
/.*\.icu\/*./ Reject
```

The problem is that any emails, including attachments, that contains anything.icuabacadada are also blocked.

It seems the second \ before the / is not working as intent. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me just take the regex out of your question:

```
/.*\.icu\/*./
 ^^                  (A) this part is not needed
   ^^^^^             (B) this matches .icu
        ^^^          (C) this matches 0, 1, 2 or any number of /
           ^         (D) this matches 1 character (any of them)
```

To get to the proper regex, you need to

- remove A (to improve performance)
- keep B
- modify C to describe one `/` character
- drop D (I presume it was placed here by a mistake, perhaps you mixed `.*` to `*.`?

So the proper regexp is:

```
/\.icu\//
```

Comment: Why '+'? Wouldn't one matched '/' be enough?

Comment: It would, let me fix that ;)

Answer (score 1):

The construct `\/*` matches any slash including no slash. Maybe `/.*\.icu\/.*/ Reject` is what you want to match only those addresses containing ".icu/". I'm not familiar with postfix regexes, but my guess is the escaped slash is correct.

**Edit**

The improved regex should be `/\.icu\// Reject` (Thanks asdmin)

Comment: You proposed `/.*\.icu\/.*/ Reject`. The initial and final `.*` have no other effect but to slow down matching

Comment: @asdmin Sorry, I only tried to fix the error and just copied the example.

Comment: the innitial .* do not work as meaning: any character?

Comment: It does work (match any characters before ".icu"), but is not needed in postfix regexes. So you can remove the first and the second `.*`.

Comment: @Kaf: regular expressions by default match anywhere in the pattern space. You can force match the beginning (`^`) or the end (`$`) of the pattern space, but that is only an option. `/.*blabla/` literally means to try matching at *every* position (implicit), then check if after *any* number of characters (`.*` part) you have `blabla`. The *any* is nested  into *every* here and cause terrible performance by forcing a loop-in-a-loop.

Comment: So if i want to block all appearance of the word blabla, case insensitive, i need to /^blbla$/ REJECT? This will block fsfsfsblablasfsffs (space)blabla.fdgdg sfblabla(space)fdgfdfg and Blaba?

Comment: `/^blbla$/` will only match, if the pattern space contains not more and not less, but *only* `blbla`.

It is so because you explicitly match the beginning and the end of the pattern space (with `^` and with `$` respectively). 

To match at least one appearance of `blbla`, independently from where it occurs in the pattern space, the fastest regular expression is simply `/blbla/`

Comment: @Kaf The rule looks okay to me, but feel free to ask a new question ;)